# Firebase push notification delay in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I'm trying to implement firebase push notification inside my android application. The problem I'm facing is that when I send notification from firebase console it takes 3 minutes of delay to be received on the device. I tried testing it on emulator as well as on mobile too. Please do let me know if anyone has any knowledge about it